# Can this query be rewritten more efficiently?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an SQL query like this:

```
select * 
from orders 
where order_session_id IN ( 
   select id order_status 
   from order_sessions 
   where order_status IN (
      select id 
      from order_status_types 
      where order_status != "Paid"
   )
)
```

This returned a hash. I wrote it in ruby but I get the feeling it can be optimized.

```
@orders = []
paid_order_status_id = OrderStatusType.find_by_order_status("Paid").id
OrderSession.where('order_status != ?',paid_order_status_id).each { |unpaid_order|
  @orders << Order.find(unpaid_order.id)
}
```

Comment: @CoderSeven Do you know that the OP is not dealing with Raw SQL and rather active record?

Comment: @CoderSeven Well you're not dealing with SQL so joins are irrelevent. Rails does joins automatically. `Post.find(1).users` finds all the users with `post_id = 1`

Comment: Ah the more you know! Thanks. I am familiar with ORMs, not ActiveRecord.

Comment: can you include your model associations for order, order_session and order_status_type?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the following association

```
OrderSession belongs_to Order
Order has_one OrderSession
```

you try

```
@orders = Order.joins(:order_session).where('order_sessions.order_status != ?', paid_order_status_id)
```

Comment: you forgot to use a placeholder "?": `@orders = Order.joins(:order_session).where('order_sessions.order_status != ?', paid_order_status_id)`